# a linear transformation with an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function mapping the open upper half plane, $\{z: \text {Im}z>0\}$ to the open unit disk, $\{z:|z|<1\}$, with $f(i)=0$. Prove that $|f(z)|\leq | \, \frac {z-i}{z+i} \,\,| $ for all $z$ in the open upper half plane.

I figure out that the function on the right hand side of the inequality, $g(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$, maps the closed upper half plane to the closed unit disk and $g(i)=0$. But I couldnt get the inequality from that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: I couldn't able to use the lemma, could you give a hint about how I can apply the lemma? Thanks a lot.

Comment: consider f\circ g^{-1}$, which is a function from the disk to itself.

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot. Thanks.